# OpenSSH sshd Privilege Separation Directory

Tags: ssh, openssh

OpenSSH 7.6p1: Why did Ubuntu change the default location of the sshd privilege separation directory from /var/empty (i.e. look at the man pages for sshd on the openssh.com web-site) to /run/sshd? This is problematic in multi-instance sshd operations in the /etc/init.d/ssh script during boot of Ubuntu.
If Ubuntu would go back to using the /var/empty directory instead of the /run/sshd directory and remove the "mkdir /run/sshd" from the init.d script, this problem would go away. Who made this decision and why?

Comment: "Who made this decision and why?" is asking for an opinion. Oh and it SHOULD be `/run/sshd` and not /var/. LInux(not just Ubuntu) is moving to a separate read only part of linux and a part that is loaded into memory. "run" is part of the latter

Comment: Well we are in a conflict between the opinions of OpenSSH and Linux. I have no problems moving to the /run standard. My request is that we implement a means of configuring the /run/sshd directory (aka: the privilege separation directory). Fixed paths in any tool are problematic; I advocate a provision for configuring the location of this directory either from sshd_config or the command line.